# Macbook Pro Mid 2012 Black Screen and No Picture On External Monitor. GPU problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My 15" non-retina Macbook Pro Mid 2012 is having some issues. The screen suddenly went out on me as I was using it. There is absolutely no picture going to the screen, so it isn't a brightness issue. I have also tried plugging into an external monitor, and no picture shows up on that either. I am sure the computer is powering up properly, as I can hear applications running in the background.

I have reset the SMC and PRAM numerous times. As far as I can tell, there has been no damage to any parts of the logic board.

Does this mean my GPU is shot and my computer could function properly if I replaced it, or are there other parts I should be inspecting?

Comment: does it work in Safe mode? did you run the apple hardware test

Comment: @Buscar웃SD pretty much tried every secondary start mode and none displayed a picture

Comment: did you install a app that could do that

Comment: @Buscar웃SD the last app I remember installing was one that allowed me to use clam mode for a certain amount of time. That was a few days ago. Could the problem be related?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD if I recall correctly it was InsomniaX

Answer (score 1):

Bad news, your GPU is shot.

Good news- you might be eligible for a [free repair by Apple](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/).